# Using the word "SING" in a C enum errors to "expected an identifier"

Tags: c++

In a header file I have the following enum:

```
namespace OBJ_VERBS {
    enum { zero, 
    CUDDLE, EMBRACE, FLIP, GROPE, HUG, 
    KISS, LICK, NUDGE, PAT, PINCH, 
    POKE, PULL, RUB, SHAKE, SQUEEZE, 
    TAP, TUG, TURN, WAVE, PEER, 
    PET, CLENCH, CURSE, NUZZLE, SNAP, 
    STROKE, TWIRL, LEAN, GRIP, SMELL,
    GRUNT, SQUEAL, SCOLD, GAZE, WIND, 
    SPIT, SPIN, DANCE, SING, 
    zTOTAL};

    const int _MAX_ = int(OBJ_VERBS::zTOTAL - 1);
}
```

I get the following error:  **Error: expected an identifier**

I tried searching the web to see if "**SING**" was a keyword, but it's not.

Any ideas?

Comment: C doesn't have namespaces.  Are you sure you're working in C?

Comment: It is indeed `C++` not `C`, but to be fair to OP, the same error would have occurred in C with a standard C `enum` (without the `namespace`).

Comment: Yes, C++.  My mistake and thank you for the correction.

Comment: Did you (explicitly) `#include` any C headers? If so, does the problem persist if you only `#include` C++ headers (like `cmath` etc)?

Comment: Knowing your platform and C++ implementation (i.e. "compiler" name and version) is relevant to this question.

Comment: I reverted your edit because answers don't go in questions! Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am betting you are including (directly or indirectly) `math.h`.

A little investigation reveals:

```
$ grep -r -w SING /usr/include/
/usr/include/math.h:#define SING 2
```

As it's `#define`d to 2, the `enum` attempts to use `2` as an enum member, which fails with the error given above.

Note that I'm (necessarily) guessing what's happening here based on the include files I have locally. It's possible you have something entirely different causing the issue, but the most likely culprit is a `#define` in an include file. See the `grep` I used above for how I found it.

This is why it's often a good idea to use (e.g.) `OV_CUDDLE`, `OV_EMBRACE` etc., to minimise collisions.

For what it's worth, the context of `SING` in `math.h` is:

```
/* Types of exceptions in the `type' field.  */
# define DOMAIN         1
# define SING           2
# define OVERFLOW       3
# define UNDERFLOW      4
# define TLOSS          5
# define PLOSS          6
```

Comment: I guess this is why C++ has namespaces.

Comment: Yes, but as I'm sure you know (so saying this for OP's benefit), namespaces don't affect preprocessor `#define` ...

Comment: If the OP only includes C++ headers (like `cmath`), then this shouldn't happen (according to the standard), shouldn't it? If it still happens, isn't it a compiler/library bug?

Comment: @Walter: I would expect a compliant and ethical C++ implementation to at least use a leading `_` so as to use the reserved "namespace" for such macros. However, since [the macro comes from SVID](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/matherr.3.html), that is not acceptable for any implementation that wishes to maintain SVID compatibility (i.e. you can't just rename someone's constant). Therefore I wouldn't be entirely surprised if `cmath` were also to define `SING` on some systems (though it doesn't on my FC11 GCC 4.4.1). It certainly _shouldn't_ be [a constant] in namespace `std`.

Comment: @Walter: AFAICT, the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) doesn't standardize `SING` at all — the word does not appear in the standard in all-caps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The C++ standard says that all global symbols that don't clash with a C++ keyword and don't start with `_` followed by an Upper case letter of starting with `__` are legal identifiers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: This macro is not from C++, nor is it from C. It's a System V thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes — I saw your comment after I hit return on mine.  Both are valid comments.

Comment: @Walter: yes, but the C++ standard isn't the only standard in the world, and quite often different standards say conflicting things. Sometimes you can control which standards are in use (`-std=c++98` vs `-std=gnu98`, for example). Sometimes you can't. In a theoretically ideal world, the problem would not arise; the real world (just in case you hadn't noticed) is not ideal and this sort of mess occasionally occurs. It's a confounded nuisance when it does occur, especially since C++ allows one header to include arbitrary others, so even if you get it working on one system, it may fail on others.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, abligh most likely found the culprit. However, according to the C++ standard the identifier `SING` should be legal and hence available for you to use. The best way to test this is

```
#ifdef SING
#  error 'SING' pre-#defined -- use only standard compatible headers.
#endif
```

If you only #include C++ standard headers (such as `cmath`) and C++ -compliable headers, this shouldn't happen. Those headers must only use identifiers which are not legal to use by the user. If the problem persists even then, you have encountered a bug/feature in the standard library implementation your using or the third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

abligh was spot-on.  I am using math.h, and here's what I found in there.

```
#define DOMAIN      _DOMAIN
#define SING        _SING
#define OVERFLOW    _OVERFLOW
#define UNDERFLOW   _UNDERFLOW
#define TLOSS       _TLOSS
#define PLOSS       _PLOSS

// Constant definitions for the exception type passed in the _exception struct
#define _DOMAIN     1   // Argument domain error
#define _SING       2   // Argument singularity
#define _OVERFLOW   3   // Overflow range error
#define _UNDERFLOW  4   // Underflow range error
#define _TLOSS      5   // Total loss of precision
#define _PLOSS      6   // Partial loss of precision
```

Thank you all for the extremely fast responses.